# DB2 duplicate key error when inserting, BUT working after select count(*)

Tags: insert, count, db2, duplicates, ibm-midrange

I have a - for me unknown - issue and I don't know what's the logic/cause behind it. When I try to insert a record in a table I get a DB2 error saying:

```
[SQL0803] Duplicate key value specified: A unique index or unique constraint *N in *N
exists over one or more columns of table TABLEXXX in SCHEMAYYY. The operation cannot 
be performed because one or more values would have produced a duplicate key in 
the unique index or constraint.
```

Which is a quite clear message to me. **But** actually there would be no duplicate key if I inserted my new record seeing what records are already in there. When I do a `SELECT COUNT(*) from SCHEMAYYY.TABLEXXX` and then try to insert the record it works flawlessly.

How can it be that when performing the `SELECT COUNT(*)` I can suddenly insert the records? Is there some sort of index associated with it which might give issues because it is out of sync? I didn't design the data model, so I don't have deep knowledge of the system yet.

The original DB2 SQL is:

```
--  Generate SQL 
--  Version:                    V6R1M0 080215 
--  Generated on:               19/12/12 10:28:39 
--  Relational Database:        S656C89D 
--  Standards Option:           DB2 for i 
CREATE TABLE TZVDB.PRODUCTCOSTS ( 
    ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( 
START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 
NO CYCLE NO ORDER 
CACHE 20 ) 
, 
PRODUCT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT NULL , 
STARTPRICE DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT NULL , 
FROMDATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL , 
TILLDATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL , 
CONSTRAINT TZVDB.PRODUCTCOSTS_PK PRIMARY KEY( ID ) ) ; 

ALTER TABLE TZVDB.PRODUCTCOSTS 
ADD CONSTRAINT TZVDB.PRODCSTS_PRDCT_FK 
FOREIGN KEY( PRODUCT_ID ) 
REFERENCES TZVDB.PRODUCT ( ID ) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Can you show us the table definition of `TABLEXXX`?  That should show the index/unique constraints you have.  Also, can you show the insert statement?

Comment: Probably something weird in your definitions, but yes, it's possible that you have a high level of optimization, with your table statistics out-of-date.  Although I thought that usually unique constraints were only enforced _after_ the `INSERT` was attempted...

Comment: Added the generated SQL from the table in the original posting.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Is this still happening?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to see the statements...but since this question is a year old...I won't old my breath.

I'm thinking the problem may be the 
GENERATED BY DEFAULT

And instead of passing NULL for the identity column, you're accidentally passing zero or some other duplicate value the first time around.

Either always pass NULL, pass a non-duplicate value or switch to GENERATED ALWAYS

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I don't know why I didn't see that back then, staring me right in the face.

Answer (score 1):

Look at preceding messages in the joblog for specifics as to what caused this.  I don't understand how the INSERT can suddenly work after the COUNT(*).  Please let us know what you find.

Since it shows `*N` (ie n/a) as the name of the index or constraing, this suggests to me that is is not a standard DB2 object, and therefore may be a "logical file" [LF] [defined with DDS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzakb%2Fldef.htm) rather than SQL, with a key structure different than what you were doing your COUNT(*) on.

Your shop may have better tools do view keys on dependent files, but the method below will work anywhere.

If your table might not be the actual "physical file", check this using Display File Description, `DSPFD TZVDB.PRODUCTCOSTS`, in a 5250 ("green screen") session.

Use the Display Database Relations command, `DSPDBR TZVDB.PRODUCTCOSTS`, to find what files are defined over your table.  You can then `DSPFD` on each of these files to see the definition of the index key. Also check there that each of these indexes is maintained `*IMMED`, rather than `*REBUILD` or `*DELAY`.  (A wild longshot guess as to a remotely possible cause of your strange anomaly.)

You will find the DB2 for i message finder [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzas2%2Frzas2finder.htm) in the [IBM i 7.1 Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp) or [other releases](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/eserver/ibmi.html)

Comment: Unique indexes are always *IMMED.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a paging issue? we seem to get -0803 on inserts occasionally when a row is being held for update and it locks a page that probably contains the index that is needed for the insert? This is only a guess but it appears to me that is what is happening.

Comment: The DB2 for i does not lock *pages*-at-a-time, only rows-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old topic, but this is what Google shown me on the first place.
I had the same issue yesterday, causing me a lot of headache. I did the same as above, checked the table definitions, keys, existing items...
Then I found out the problem was with my INSERT statement. It was trying to insert to identical records at once, but as the constraint prevented the commit, I could not find anything in the database.
Advice: review your INSERT statement carefully! :)